# lambda expression and casting

Tags: c#, lambda

```
        var objectType = cmbObjectType.SelectedItem as Type;
        var property = cmbProperty.SelectedItem as PropertyInfo;
        var oper = cmbOperator.SelectedValue;

        var item = Expression.Parameter(objectType);
        var prop = Expression.Property(item, property);

        BinaryExpression condition=null;

        var filtered = tlproject.TlObjects.Where(obj => obj.GetType().Equals(objectType)).AsQueryable();

...
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TLObject, bool>>(condition, item);                    
        var results = filtered.Where(lambda);
```

This doesnt work because objects inherit from TLObject giving me errors like

> Additional information: ParameterExpression of type
>   'TLObjects.Pipe' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type
>   'TLObjects.Base.TLObject'

How can I fix this?
**UPDATE**
This seems to work

```
  var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TLObject));
    var itemConverted=Expression.Convert(item, objectType);
    var prop = Expression.Property(itemConverted, property);
```

Comment: If you've found a solution, feel free to post it as an answer rather than an edit